# Polynomial regression In libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, openoffice-calc

If we have certain X-Y columns, and the data does not look linear when plotted, we may want to use a polynomial to fit the data.

How do we fit a polynomial model other than using a `ax+b` fit on the linear regression in Libreoffice ?

I use libreoffice 7.2, in Ubuntu 22

Have thoroughly read this link already https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-a-polynomial-curve-fit-function-s-in-calc/116 but there is no such settings currently, as far as I can see, and the regression barely has any options.

This can be easily done even in google sheets, [see here if interested.](https://www.statology.org/polynomial-regression-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 1):

Procedure:

I finally got it:

- Method 1.

  Press in the data points of the chart (or maybe selecting two columns works as well)
  Go to insert > trendline
- Method 2

  Just right clicking in the data and select insert trendline

There is probably other ways, but I do not think there is currently a function (LINEST and TREND dont do it) to achieve this.

Same idea is valid for google sheets (make a plot and add a trend line, and put show equation to get the polynomial.)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJJ8q.png)

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a column with your x values and an adjacent column with x² values, then add a column with y values. To use the numerical values in calculations outside a graph, enter the Linest function as an array on three cells (ctrl+shift+enter). You will then get the coefficients of your square fit. I would recommend to enter with parameters as follows: LINEST(Y values; X,X² values;1;1). You can also add higher degrees like that (X³ in third column etc). I would recommend to have a look at the R² value to compare different regressions and decide which fits your data best (the closer to 1 the better). Using higher degrees may not always improve fit quality and may not reflect actual model properties of what you are looking at. The Linest function is a very helpful and powerful tool to analyse data.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers - in this case a self-answered one - ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help].